# android osx my droid does not show up on my mac

Tags: android, macos

I have a motorola flipside.  I just started trying to do eclipse development on the mac with it.  After installing eclipse etc... I can't seem to connect to my android from my mac.  When I plug the phone in, the phone shows the usb connection, and I have USB debugging enabled on the phone.  But the phone does not show up as a target device in eclipse.  And when I do the following:

adb devices

no device are found

I've been looking for osx drivers and unable to find them.

Comment: Okay it took quite a bit of digging around and a couple of calls to motorola but I found out the answer is that Motorola Media Link for the Mac has to be installed.  You can get it here:   http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/Software/Motorola-Media-Link-Mac-Version-US-EN

Comment: post your answer and accept your answer by probably two days later. so that others can get the benefit.

Comment: Yeah... I tried to answer my own question but I have to wait another 7 hours because of my relatively new status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took quite a bit of digging around and a couple calls to motorola but the answer is to install Motorola Media Link on the mac.  The URL to find it is as follows:

http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/Software/Motorola-Media-Link-Mac-Version-US-EN

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about MacOSX. But in Linux ubuntu i need to write a file in etc/udev/rules.d location . file name 90-android.rules 
With Content

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bb4", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="18d1", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="22b8", SYMLINK+="android_adb", MODE="0666"

Search same on the google. you will get something related